# How can I send a specific support ticket auto response based off of recipient email address?

Tags: case, email2case, case-object

I have Salesforce configured for email-to-case. We have multiple email addresses customers can send to: support@foo.com support2@foo.com support3@foo.com.  I'd like to send back a unique initial case acknowledment auto response if (and only if) the initial email went to support3@foo.com.  how can I do this? I don't see a case object I can trigger on that includes the email address the request was received on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to record the source email address. One way to do this without code is to add that specific source email as a value in the Case Origin field and you could use that as your auto response criteria.

If you are just using "email" as the Case Origin, and want to continue to do so, you could still do the above then use a workflow rule to copy the email address to a custom field and also set the Case Origin back to "email". I personally use this approach as it allows:

- High level reporting on Case Origin
- Reporting on Case volume per specific email address
- Ability to configure specific auto responses

I can add more detail on the workflow part if helpful.

**Further info:**

When setting up an email to case address you will seen like below. Before this create the relevant Case Origin value. Anytime a Case gets created via this email 2 case address it will have this Case Origin applied:

[image]

Comment: You mean record the recipient email address on the address/inbox that received the message right? I don't necessarily care who sent the message, at least not for the purpose of creating a custom case acknowledgment... I just want to send back a custom response if the initial email was sent to support3@foo.com.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, I'ved added a bit more detail/screenshot. If I understand correctly I don't see why you can't use the case origin field.

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what I needed and resolved the issue.